# Cygwin: get a path's stored capitalization

Tags: cygwin, case-sensitivity

Cygwin is case-insensitive in the manner of Windows, e. g.:

```
$ touch ABC; rstr=$(openssl rand -base64 12); echo $rstr; echo $rstr > AbC; cat abc
dGRMOHqqoy0/nc96
dGRMOHqqoy0/nc96

$ ls | grep -i abc
ABC
```

The cases of characters in a file or directory name are stored but ignored when doing operations on it.

`ABC`, `AbC` and `abc` select the identical file.

Is there a robust way to get for a given file path or directory path the capitalization *as stored?* The grep trick quickly becomes very cumbersome.

Comment: It's not so much Cygwin as the NTFS filesystem underneath it

Comment: @roaima I don't see the logic here. NTFS prohibits the same filenames merely differing by case in the same location. This is simply a restriction that Cygwin also must adhere to. But that does not imply Cygwin has to be liberal about the file selection and ignore the case there, too. That's a deliberate decision.

Comment: I'm missing the rationale here. In your example you could be consistent either by using a variable for the target filename or by writing the code. Clearly it's an example to illustrate your point, but I'm not sure why it actually matters. A glob will match the case as stored (`for i in ???; do echo "> $i <"; done`). There's also the `nocaseglob` setting for `shopt` that will allow globs to match without regard to case, which controls whether or not `ls a*` will match your file `ABC`.

Comment: @roaima for normal interactive operations on Cygwin it is not a problem. But there are situations when the case matters, especially when communicating with a real Linux, which is case-sensitive. For example in Cygwin `$PWD` is set to the working directory as *entered* by the user, not *as stored.* If your local directory structure is supposed to mirror the one on the server, problems arise if the user did a `cd` without caring about the case, which Cygwin allows them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, and with the `extendedglob` option on, you can do:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ printf '%s\n' (#i)path/to/file
Path/to/FILE
```

To get the `path/to/file` with the stored case.

In `ksh93`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ~(i)path/to/file
Path/to/FILE
```

(beware that if there's no match, that will expand to `~(i)path/to/file`, ksh93 has no equivalent to  the  `nomatch` or `failglob` options, though you could use `~(Ni)path/to/file` for that to expand to nothing when it doesn't match)

In `bash` with the `extglob`, `failglob` and `nocaseglob` options on, you can do:

```
$ shopt -s extglob failglob nocaseglob
$ printf '%s\n' @(path)/@(to)/@(file)
Path/to/FILE
```

Without `extglob`, you can also do `printf '%s\n' [p]ath/[t]o/[f]ile`, though that's harder to  automate reliably.

(in any case, underneath the shell does the equivalent of your `ls | grep -i`, that is, it has to read the full directory contents to find matching files. Note that like for `grep -i`, case comparison is done as per the locale, it may differ from the way NTFS does case comparison)

Comment: found another solution `cygpath $(cygpath -m -l /path/to/file)` in bash don't know if that's robust.

Comment: @Amaterasu, good find. You'd probably want `file=$(cygpath -ml -- "$file") && file=$(cygpath -- "$file")`. Also beware it resolves symlinks. As always with command substitution, you'll have problem with paths ending in newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Not exaclty what you asked for, but may be you are interested.
I took this somewhere that I do not remember, but it works:

> Case Sensitve NTFS
>
> You can't enable case sensitivity for a single folder or volume on
> Windows, but you can do it for the whole system.
>
> You need to change the value of the Registry key
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
> Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive
>
> from 1 to 0 and reboot the system.

If you do so, you need also to change from `posix=0` to `posix=1`
any mount on `/etc/fstab` eg:

```
d:\cyg_pub /pub  NTFS binary,posix=1,nouser 0 0
```

after that

```
$ cd /tmp

$ touch Pippo

$ touch PIppo

$ touch PIPpo

$ ls P*
Pippo  PIppo  PIPpo
```